# LI Bullet aligned with second line in UL. Why and how to correct it?

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with a UL list containing (for now) 2 links.
As shown in the following image, whenever the browser window width goes under approx. 1340 px, the list gets too narrow to display the link on one single line. The problem is the bullet is aligned with the second line, not the first one, as it should.

As I cannot post an image, I will try to illustrate it in ASCII.

#### Expected rendering:

- Link 1 short
- Link 2 a bit too
  long

### What I get:

- Link 1 short

  Link 2 a bit too
- long

You can see it (site is staged) in the third column of the footer at http://014.0d8.myftpupload.com/abonner-infolettre/

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks correct in Chrome.

Comment: Applied css or other html code might be affecting it, as I cant recreate this problem. Might be helpful to post relevant css and html code

Comment: You may be right isherwood. It didn't show up in my searches. I'll take a look at it! :)

Comment: @David : I use Chrome, tested it with FF and Safari, all have same behavior, resize your window in width down to around 1400 and then again up until the 2nd list element get on two lines.

Answer (score 2):

Marked to close as duplicate, but here's your solution:

```
.widget ul li a, .widget ol li a {
    ...
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `a` tag, that's inline-block. There are two different solutions, but in the same way:

```
  .widget ul li a, .widget ol li a {
       display: inline;
   }

  .widget ul li a, .widget ol li a {
       vertical-align:top
  }
```

You can test it, both of them works.